# Which group do I need to add a user to to give them access to editing network connections?

Tags: networking, network-manager, users

I'd specifically like them to be able to use the Network Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it by narrowing the scope of sudo users and commands.

Create a new sudoers file by any name:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/network-config
```

Add the contents of the file (with real usernames and any real additional commands of course)...

```
User_Alias NET_CFG_USERS = username1, username2, username3
Cmnd_Alias NET_CFG_CMNDS = /usr/bin/nm-connection-editor, command2, command3
NET_CFG_USERS ALL = (root) NET_CFG_CMNDS
```

Save & quit. Now the named users can open a terminal to change settings, using their own password:

```
sudo nm-connection-editor
```

Success?

Some notes: It is **critical** that you use `visudo` and no other method for this, or else [sudo may break](http://www.peppertop.com/blog/?p=1015). Please consider reading that post first to make sure you avoid the problem. In short, sudo appears to have been programmed not to work at all if the permissions of a sudoers file is not 0440. The `visudo` command creates files with the right permissions. Whereas, were you to do this:

```
sudo -e /etc/sudoers.d/network-config
```

you could temporarily wind up without administrative access.